# Specifying RESTful API Response Based on Query Parameter in openAPI

Tags: rest, openapi

I am designing an openAPI specification for a project. The project is a REST API that provides information about hotels.

I want to either provide detailed information about the hotel, or a quick summary. My understanding of REST is that, since both of these relate to the same object in my data store, I should be using a query parameter to request the different data types.

So what I am looking for is a way to specify different API behaviors based on query parameters of a given request. Here is my current implementation. I am looking at an endpoint like this:

```
/hotels/{hotelId}?detail={detailLevel}
```

where `{hotelId}` is an integer and `{detailLevel}` is an optional string enum that can either be `summary` or `robust`.

If `detail=robust`, the response should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Hilton Grand Vacations on the Las Vegas Strip"
  "streetAddress": "2650 Las Vegas Blvd S",
  "city": "Las Vegas",
  "state": "NV",
  "zipCode": 89109
  "rating": 4.4,
  "minimumPrice": 125,
  "availableRooms": 10,
}
```

If `detail=summary`, the response should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "Hilton Grand Vacations on the Las Vegas Strip",
  "rating": 4,
  "zipCode": 89109,
  "available": true
}
```

I don't want to have a specification that covers both of these responses, because I want to make it easy to validate any given response based on its URL parameter (for example, `"available"` should not be a field when `detail=robust`). So far, I have not been able to find a way to specify different return behaviors in openAPI based on query parameters.

Is there a way to specify behavior based on query parameters? Alternatively, should I change my API endpoint to something like `/hotels/{hotelId}/{detailLevel}`?

Comment: I am not sure though, will MatrixVariables be useful in anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my disappointment, I have learned that openAPI [does not support](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/164) to use of query parameters to differentiate endpoints with the same path.

I will be specifying my paths as `/hotels/{hotelId}/{detailLevel}` instead.

Comment: Nice reference. BTW I'd like to mention that this is my issue too, sometimes I think I need to use graphql instead of restful api. But I am not sure anyway.